# Google App Engine - ByteString query fails

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I am working on a Go application in which I have an Entity with a Property that holds an identifying token which is a random string of bytes. I am storing this property as a ByteString, and in my development environment I have been able to query for this property using a filter of the form:

```
// token is a []byte
idTok := datastore.ByteString(token)
q := ds.NewQuery("Entity").Filter("IDToken =", idTok)

var entities []Entity
keys, err := q.GetAll(c, &entities)
```

But unfortunately, when deployed as a module to GAE, this query returns the error: `datastore: bad query filter value type: unsupported datastore value type: datastore.ByteString`, which is confusing since I thought the purpose of the ByteString type is to be able to index shorter amounts of binary data under 500 bytes.

I first switched over to using the ByteString type based on the second answer to this SO question: [Golang - Appengine datastore filter query with []byte comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25829202/golang-appengine-datastore-filter-query-with-byte-comparison)

Comment: Can you confirm that `len(token)` is not greater than `500`? Also what version of Go SDK are you using? 1.2 or 1.4beta? If the latter, in your `app.yaml` config file did you specify `api_version: go1.4beta`?

Comment: Yes, I am generating the tokens myself and they are 64 bytes long. The error actually even occurs when there are no entities at all in the database, so it would seem to be unrelated to the context of any entity. I only have the api version specified as `api_version: go1`. Do you know where differences between versions are documented?

Comment: I found release noted for the GAE Go runtime environment here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkForGoReleaseNotes that state in version 1.9.11 support was added for `ByteString`, with the note: "Add `ByteString` type to allow short indexable byte slices." I confirmed that my code is running on `Google App Engine/1.9.18` with a call to `appengine.ServerSoftware()`. I'm not sure how to see what version of Go the app is running on, but it would seem that the Go version should be orthogonal to the app engine functionality provided through the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue resolved itself about a week later. Since it only appeared in the module environment, I am guessing that some piece of their code had not been updated to support the ByteString type, and now is. Works great now!